# It is possible to declare an ArrayList<Subject> of ArrayLists<Student>?

Tags: java

I'm creating a java program where I have to make a database for an university. 
There are two classes: Subject and Student, so I want to declare an ArrayList of ArrayLists, is that possible? If it is, how could I add elements? Thank's a lot!

Comment: Ooops, missed the part on ArrayList of ArrayLists...adym

Comment: Yes it is possible.  But I don't think it solves your problem.  The solution requires modeling that a given student is enrolled for multiple subjects (a simple list), and a subject has multiple students enrolled in it (a simple list).  No need for lists of lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare a List of Lists as follows:

```
List<List<Type>> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

However, from reading your question, I think you are trying to create a list of `Student` for each `Subject` and so a more appropriate data structure would be a Map which maps a list of `Student` to a `Subject`.

```
Map<Subject, List<Student>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

You can read the Java tutorial on Maps [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html).

Comment: If I use a Map, how can I assign a list of Student for each Subject?

Answer (score 0):

sure it is possible, but what is a reason to do that?

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<?>> topList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<?>>();
        ArrayList<Student> studentsList = new ArrayList<Student>();
        ArrayList<Subject> subjectsList = new ArrayList<Subject>();

        studentsList.add(new Student("Vadim"));

        subjectsList.add(new Subject("Java"));

        topList.add(subjectsList);
        topList.add(studentsList);

        System.out.println("Subject(0):" + ((Subject)topList.get(0).get(0)).getTopic());
        System.out.println("Student(0):" + ((Student)topList.get(1).get(0)).getFullName());
```